# C++ making Hash of Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multimap

I have a problem with the creation of a hash of arrays. I need a Single Key - Multi Data system:

```
multimap <Type, vector<type> > var;
```

But how I can add elements to the vector?

Example: `key = 3;`

Now I need to append some elements into the vector whose key is 3.

Creating a temp-vector not an answer because I don't know when I need to input element into the vector with the current key.

sorry, understand my problem. i need fast-access struct, that will be operate with ~50,000 words with length ~20 each. 
and i need something like tree. 
also, have question:
     how quick STL-structures, like vector,map,multimap and other?

Comment: Please vote to reopen; it’s a real question, and now it should at least be understandable.

Comment: @Konrad agreed, you can ask in Meta many are roaming there..

Comment: @Shadow Even better: I’m asking in the chat.

Comment: As David Hammen says, why do you need a multimap rather than a normal map? In a normal map you can access the vector directly as `var[3]`. Otherwise get an iterator and dereference it.

Comment: okay, i can use them, but i need quick-access. 
how about quick-access with STL?

Comment: @loldop: How would a multimap be any faster? In fact, your question isn't even well-formed, because for `key = 3` there are potentially *many* vectors that you could manipulate. Which one should it be? Maybe you can step back and describe your larger-scale goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the answer to your question you can look at the slides under point 6. at this site https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece250/Lectures/Slides/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Care to summarize the "slides under point 6"? I for one do not open powerpoint presentations from a remote site. Too many chances of a virus. The odds of infection are vastly improved if that remove site is a college.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `std::map <KeyType, std::vector<SomeType> >`, or some other collection as the value type? This gives you control over how to operate on the value collection. A multimap to me seems like a low-level form of `std::map <KeyType, std::list<SomeType> >`, but with none of the flexibility of a list.